# Inconsistent Azure Pipeline. Error: AKV10032: Invalid issuer

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault, azure-pipelines-yaml

We are facing some issues with all the pipeline a specific Azure DevOps project. When we are running it getting below error.

All these projects are calling KeyVault from the code to get the secret during build (we are using Build Cake extension) , it is failing now in pipeline. All these pipelines were working previously, even the pipelines working previously (not modified) also not working under same project.

{"error":{"code":"Unauthorized","message":"AKV10032: Invalid issuer. Expected one of https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/, https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/, https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/, found [https://sts.windows.net/72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47/."}}](https://sts.windows.net/72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47/.%22%7D%7D)

```
`- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Cake Build with Azure CLI and Dotnet'
  inputs:
    scriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    azureSubscription: 'Found-TEST'
    addSpnToEnvironment: true
    inlineScript: |
      az account set -s "XXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXX-"
      az account list
      dotnet run --project ${{parameters.project}}`
```

Steps/fixes we have followed

1. Updated PAT Checked Service connection – it is correct
2. Tried to access KeyVault from pipeline. Working.
3. Tested the code locally to get the secret – Working
4. We have set the subscription properly before calling dotnet project

Comment: Is it using defaultazurecredentials from code ?

Comment: No we are using ChainedTokenCredential credential = new ChainedTokenCredential(new ManagedIdentityCredential(), new EnvironmentCredential(), new VisualStudioCredential(), new AzureCliCredential());

Comment: I saw an error using the cli credentials. Try settings the tenant as env variable.

Comment: Where do we set this? Is it in the application.settings or as a parameter?

Comment: env variables. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme#environment-variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few related open issues on github:

- [[BUG] Since 2 days our pipeline can not get secrets from the keyvault because not the defined TenantId is used #5908](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/5908)
- [[BUG] Since 2 days our pipeline can not get secrets from the keyvault because not the defined TenantId is used #29902](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/29902)

As a workaround for the moment, you could set the AAD Tenant Id as environment variable (powershell sample):

```yaml
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Cake Build with Azure CLI and Dotnet'
  inputs:
    scriptType: pscore
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    azureSubscription: 'Found-TEST'
    addSpnToEnvironment: true
    inlineScript: |
      az account set -s "XXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXX-"
      az account list
      $env:AZURE_TENANT_ID = "$($env:tenantId)";
      dotnet run --project ${{parameters.project}}
```

Comment: Awesome. This workaround fixed my pipeline. Thanks a ton, Thomas.

Comment: I had the same issue last friday and saw your post so better share it :-)